# js + php : Why did the EventSource can't get any responses?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, event-stream

I have a stream response like following:

I'm using Laravel as backend

```php
public function stream() {
    return response()->stream(function() {
        while (true) {

            if (connection_aborted()) {
                Log::debug('aborted');
                break;
            }
            
            echo "\nevent: process\n", 'data: {"time": ' . time() . '}', "\n\n";
            Log::debug('echoed');

            ob_flush();
            flush();

            sleep(3);
        }
    }, 200, [
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/event-stream',
    ]);
}
```

frontend:

```js
let stream = new EventSource(`http://example.test/api/stream`);
stream.addEventListener('process', event => {
    console.log(event.data)
});
```

as the code show, it's expected to `console.log(event.data)` every 3 seconds.

Although I can get the `echoed` Logs (but not the `aborted`) in backend, but I can't get any output in the console of browser.

I've googled but nothing helps. How did this error occur and how can it be solved?

Thanks a lot for any replys!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a response header

```php
'X-Accel-Buffering' => 'no'
```

---

Setting this to “no” will allow unbuffered responses suitable for Comet and HTTP streaming applications. Setting this to “yes” will allow the response to be cached.

Refrences:

1. [x-accel-buffering](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-buffering)
2. [Event Stream - Server-Send Events](https://dev.to/mesadhan/event-stream-server-send-events-5afk)